# Can mysql cli check a file without committing it?

Tags: mysql

I have sql in a file, which contains a number of statements. How can I get mysql to check the validity of the sql without executing it?

Something like

```
mysql --check-only input.sql
```

At a minimum, I need syntax to be checked.

Ideally, it would also attempt to e.g. insert data and check constraints. Basically wrapping the whole file in an implicit transaction which is automatically rolled-back.

Can mysql CLI do this?

Comment: What more do you need than i.e. https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/, or https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/  .   Because after a syntax check you still need to validate the correctness of the script.

Comment: Is it an option to use transactions?

Comment: @Luuk this has to be via command-line

Comment: @Progman yes, the scripts themselves do not contain transactions

Comment: @spraff Does your SQL script contains DDL statements which might be [problematic to rollback](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cannot-roll-back.html)?

Comment: @Progman yes, they create tables and routines

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the following, as you seem to be okay with using transactions:

`mysql --init-command="SET autocommit=0;BEGIN;" < input.sql`

What this will do is it will just start a transaction, process the SQL inside input.sql (including checks on syntax and inserts). Then, the process will finish without a `COMMIT;` being issued which will have the server rollback the whole thing.